# Why would adding a send() call make a previous send() call fail?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, send

Code is at the bottom.

The send() command on line 207 works fine on it's own. However, when I add the send() command on line 218, the first one fails - giving the error, "Bad address". I've confirmed that the second send() command isn't actually executed.

I'm completely lost here...

[image: The confusing code in question]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: Is this code part of a loop? Maybe it's the second `send()` from the previous iteration that's causing the first one to fail the next time.

Comment: Why are you using `BUFFER_SIZE` as the length to send, even though you're sending different sized strings?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating undefined behavior by using `BUFFER_SIZE` as the amount to send, since this isn't likely to be the lengths of the two strings. Adding the second `send()` call may be changing the memory layout of the strings, which results in the error you're getting.

It should be:

```
send(newsock_fd, "No such command in history", sizeof "No such command in history", 0);
```

If you don't want to send the trailing null byte, subtract 1 from `sizeof`.